# GoogleApiClient actual and functional tutorial for Android Studio - find a bug

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-api-client

I'd like to create a complete tutorial for connecting to Google API via GoogleApiClient and Android Studio, because it seems tutorials over the Internet including the one from Google is not exactly working.

I'm gonna post some code here and hopefully with your help I'll be able to find all the bugs and problems. **Now the problem is that `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient)` returns NULL Person.**

The most working code seems to be Google Plus Quickstart for Eclipse from [Git](https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android). Unfortunately neither this one works.

### Cook Book

1. Create Project in [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project)
2. **Name** a project and leave **Project ID** unchanged (not important)
3. **Create** & wait
4. select **API & Auth** from left menu, set **Google+ API** as ON (it'll be set by default)
5. select **Consent screen** from menu, set email and product name as you want
6. select **Credentials** from menu, then **Create a new Client ID**, box will appear
7. select **Installed application**, then **Android**
8. package name is `com.google.android.gms.plus.sample.quickstart`
9. run `keytool -list -v -keystore "~\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android` from the command window
10. find `SHA1: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:.......` line in the output and put the SHA1 hash to **Signing certificate fingerprin**t field
11. Enable **Deep Linking** and **Create client ID**
12. The code:

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.sample.quickstart;

        import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
        import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
        import com.google.android.gms.plus.People;
        import com.google.android.gms.plus.People.LoadPeopleResult;
        import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
        import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;
        import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.PersonBuffer;

        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.app.Dialog;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.content.DialogInterface;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Android Google+ Quickstart activity.
 *
 * Demonstrates Google+ Sign-In and usage of the Google+ APIs to retrieve a
 * users profile information.
 */
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult>, View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String TAG = "android-plus-quickstart";

    private static final int STATE_DEFAULT = 0;
    private static final int STATE_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int STATE_IN_PROGRESS = 2;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    private static final int DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR = 0;

    private static final String SAVED_PROGRESS = "sign_in_progress";

    // GoogleApiClient wraps our service connection to Google Play services and
    // provides access to the users sign in state and Google's APIs.
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // We use mSignInProgress to track whether user has clicked sign in.
    // mSignInProgress can be one of three values:
    //
    //       STATE_DEFAULT: The default state of the application before the user
    //                      has clicked 'sign in', or after they have clicked
    //                      'sign out'.  In this state we will not attempt to
    //                      resolve sign in errors and so will display our
    //                      Activity in a signed out state.
    //       STATE_SIGN_IN: This state indicates that the user has clicked 'sign
    //                      in', so resolve successive errors preventing sign in
    //                      until the user has successfully authorized an account
    //                      for our app.
    //   STATE_IN_PROGRESS: This state indicates that we have started an intent to
    //                      resolve an error, and so we should not start further
    //                      intents until the current intent completes.
    private int mSignInProgress;

    // Used to store the PendingIntent most recently returned by Google Play
    // services until the user clicks 'sign in'.
    private PendingIntent mSignInIntent;

    // Used to store the error code most recently returned by Google Play services
    // until the user clicks 'sign in'.
    private int mSignInError;

    private SignInButton mSignInButton;
    private Button mSignOutButton;
    private Button mRevokeButton;
    private TextView mStatus;
    private ListView mCirclesListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mCirclesAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> mCirclesList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mSignOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
        mRevokeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.revoke_access_button);
        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_status);
        mCirclesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.circles_list);

        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSignOutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRevokeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        mCirclesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mCirclesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.circle_member, mCirclesList);
        mCirclesListView.setAdapter(mCirclesAdapter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSignInProgress = savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, STATE_DEFAULT);
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
        // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and
        // connection failed callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our
        // app uses and which OAuth 2.0 scopes our app requests.
        return new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, mSignInProgress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            // We only process button clicks when GoogleApiClient is not transitioning
            // between connected and not connected.
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signing_in);
                    resolveSignInError();
                    break;
                case R.id.sign_out_button:
                    // We clear the default account on sign out so that Google Play
                    // services will not return an onConnected callback without user
                    // interaction.
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    break;
                case R.id.revoke_access_button:
                    // After we revoke permissions for the user with a GoogleApiClient
                    // instance, we must discard it and create a new one.
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    // Our sample has caches no user data from Google+, however we
                    // would normally register a callback on revokeAccessAndDisconnect
                    // to delete user data so that we comply with Google developer
                    // policies.
                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /* onConnected is called when our Activity successfully connects to Google
     * Play services.  onConnected indicates that an account was selected on the
     * device, that the selected account has granted any requested permissions to
     * our app and that we were able to establish a service connection to Google
     * Play services.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Reaching onConnected means we consider the user signed in.
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");

        // Update the user interface to reflect that the user is signed in.
        mSignInButton.setEnabled(false);
        mSignOutButton.setEnabled(true);
        mRevokeButton.setEnabled(true);

        // Retrieve some profile information to personalize our app for the user.
        Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
        if(currentUser != null) {
            mStatus.setText(String.format(
                    getResources().getString(R.string.signed_in_as),
                    currentUser.getDisplayName()));
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "CURRENT USER IS NULL");
        }

        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
                .setResultCallback(this);

        // Indicate that the sign in process is complete.
        mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
    }

    /* onConnectionFailed is called when our Activity could not connect to Google
     * Play services.  onConnectionFailed indicates that the user needs to select
     * an account, grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might
        // be returned in onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());

        if (result.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.API_UNAVAILABLE) {
            // An API requested for GoogleApiClient is not available. The device's current
            // configuration might not be supported with the requested API or a required component
            // may not be installed, such as the Android Wear application. You may need to use a
            // second GoogleApiClient to manage the application's optional APIs.
        } else if (mSignInProgress != STATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
            // We do not have an intent in progress so we should store the latest
            // error resolution intent for use when the sign in button is clicked.
            mSignInIntent = result.getResolution();
            mSignInError = result.getErrorCode();

            if (mSignInProgress == STATE_SIGN_IN) {
                // STATE_SIGN_IN indicates the user already clicked the sign in button
                // so we should continue processing errors until the user is signed in
                // or they click cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

        // In this sample we consider the user signed out whenever they do not have
        // a connection to Google Play services.
        onSignedOut();
    }

    /* Starts an appropriate intent or dialog for user interaction to resolve
     * the current error preventing the user from being signed in.  This could
     * be a dialog allowing the user to select an account, an activity allowing
     * the user to consent to the permissions being requested by your app, a
     * setting to enable device networking, etc.
     */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mSignInIntent != null) {
            // We have an intent which will allow our user to sign in or
            // resolve an error.  For example if the user needs to
            // select an account to sign in with, or if they need to consent
            // to the permissions your app is requesting.

            try {
                // Send the pending intent that we stored on the most recent
                // OnConnectionFailed callback.  This will allow the user to
                // resolve the error currently preventing our connection to
                // Google Play services.
                mSignInProgress = STATE_IN_PROGRESS;
                startIntentSenderForResult(mSignInIntent.getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Sign in intent could not be sent: "
                        + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Attempt to connect to
                // get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Google Play services wasn't able to provide an intent for some
            // error types, so we show the default Google Play services error
            // dialog which may still start an intent on our behalf if the
            // user can resolve the issue.
            showDialog(DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // If the error resolution was successful we should continue
                    // processing errors.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                } else {
                    // If the error resolution was not successful or the user canceled,
                    // we should stop processing errors.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                }

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    // If Google Play services resolved the issue with a dialog then
                    // onStart is not called so we need to re-attempt connection here.
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
        if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            mCirclesList.clear();
            PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
            try {
                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    mCirclesList.add(personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                }
            } finally {
                personBuffer.close();
            }

            mCirclesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error requesting visible circles: " + peopleData.getStatus());
        }
    }

    private void onSignedOut() {
        // Update the UI to reflect that the user is signed out.
        mSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
        mSignOutButton.setEnabled(false);
        mRevokeButton.setEnabled(false);

        mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);

        mCirclesList.clear();
        mCirclesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason.
        // We call connect() to attempt to re-establish the connection or get a
        // ConnectionResult that we can attempt to resolve.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id) {
            case DIALOG_PLAY_SERVICES_ERROR:
                if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(mSignInError)) {
                    return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                            mSignInError,
                            this,
                            RC_SIGN_IN,
                            new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services resolution cancelled");
                                    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                                    mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);
                                }
                            });
                } else {
                    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setMessage(R.string.play_services_error)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.close,
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services error could not be "
                                                    + "resolved: " + mSignInError);
                                            mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                                            mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);
                                        }
                                    }).create();
                }
            default:
                return super.onCreateDialog(id);
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     Copyright (C) 2012 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dip">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dip">
        <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
            android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sign_out_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/sign_out_button_name"
            android:enabled="false" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/revoke_access_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/revoke_access_button_name"
            android:enabled="false" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
        android:text="@string/status_signed_out" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/circles_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/circles_title" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/circles_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Google+ SDK Sample</string>
    <string name="circles_title">Visible circles:</string>
    <string name="sign_out_button_name">Sign out</string>
    <string name="revoke_access_button_name">Revoke</string>

    <string name="status_sign_in_required">Sign-in required</string>
    <string name="status_sign_in_error">Error signing in: %s</string>
    <string name="status_loading">Loading…</string>
    <string name="status_signing_in">Signing in with Google+…</string>
    <string name="status_signed_out">Signed out</string>
    <string name="status_revoke_access">Revoked access</string>
    <string name="status_revoke_access_error">Error revoking access: %s</string>
    <string name="signed_in_as">Signed in as %s</string>

    <!-- Used if there was an error loading the signed in user's name. -->
    <string name="unknown_person">Unknown</string>
    <string name="play_services_error">Google Play services is not available.  This application will close.</string>
    <string name="close">Close</string>
    <string name="profile_picture">User\'s profile picture.</string>

</resources>
```

and AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sample.quickstart"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<!-- which permissions are needed? -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle(Module:app) - add google play services:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
}
```

Now, please help me finish this once and for all. Is the problem in the code? It is caused by wrong keystore? Is the keystore in `~/.android/debug.keystore` working only for Eclipse and should I make another one somehow?

**UPDATE**
Log:

```
12-18 17:33:31.874  31095-31107/com.sample.quickstart I/LoadedApk﹕ connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.gms.plus.service.PlusService
12-18 17:33:32.284  31095-31095/com.sample.quickstart I/android-plus-quickstart﹕ onConnected
12-18 17:33:32.294  31095-31095/com.sample.quickstart E/android-plus-quickstart﹕ CURRENT USER IS NULL
```

Comment: Can you post the log? Usually you can see the issue in the log.

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson right at the bottom of my post

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson I just noticed a thing. Log says CURRENT USER IS NULL when trying to getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) but onResult() method displays user's circles without error.